# Display svg on HTML with jQuery request

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, svg, get-request

I'm trying to get this avatar from an API to appear on my HTML when I click the button but it does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#generate").click(function(){
        var c= $("#c").val().split(",");

        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/male/example.svg",
            dataType: "svg"
        })
            .done(function(result){
                $('#result').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + result + '" />');
            })

            .fail(function(error){
                console.log(error);
            });
    })


 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svg` is not a valid dataType for an AJAX request. Also, you cannot set the content of an SVG file as the base64 encoded content of an `img` element.

To do what you require needs no AJAX at all. Just set the `src` of the `img` element to the URL of the `svg` file:

```html
<img src="https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/male/example.svg" />
```

Comment: The reason I need the AJAX is because I want to switch up the URL so it would actually look like this: "https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/" + c[0]+ "/" + c[1] + ".svg" ------- c[0] and c[1] being user inputs

Comment: You don't need AJAX for that. You can dynamically amend the `src` based on user input using `prop()`.

Comment: Ohh okay, sorry im a beginner. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

To do it with AJAX you could do this:

```
  $("#generate").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
          method: 'GET',
          url: "https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/male/example.svg",
          dataType: "html"
      })

      .done(function(result){
          $('#result').html(result);
      })

      .fail(function(error){
          console.log(error);
      });
  })
```